# Saving Array of Custom Object with NSCoding

Tags: swift, swift2, nscoding

I am trying to make an alarm clock app to learn how to work with saving arrays of custom objects.

I have my project setup with a custom 'Alarm' object that contains all the information about each alarm and I have created a class that inherits NSObject and NSCoding.

Here is the Alarm Object Class

```
import Foundation

class Alarm : NSObject {
    var name : String
    var active : Bool
    var days : [String]
    var sound : [String:Int] //Will change later...... I think?.....
    var time : NSDate

    init(name : String, active : Bool, days : [String], sound : [String:Int], time : NSDate) {
        self.name = name
        self.active = active
        self.days = days
        self.sound = sound
        self.time = time
    }
}
```

Heres my Custom Class that inherits NSObject and NSCoding

```
import UIKit

class Alarms: NSObject, NSCoding {
    var alarmList : [Alarm]

    init(alarmList : [Alarm]) {
        self.alarmList = alarmList
    }

    required convenience init?(coder decoder: NSCoder) {
        guard let alarmList = decoder.decodeObjectForKey("alarms") as? [Alarm]
            else { return nil }

        self.init(
            alarmList : alarmList
        )
   }

    func encodeWithCoder(aCoder: NSCoder) {
        aCoder.encodeObject(alarmList, forKey: "alarms")
   }
}
```

I have a save function connected to a button for testing purposes. Here is that function.

```
func save(sender: AnyObject?) {
    //Save with NSKeyArchiver
    print("Save: \(path)")

    var success = false

    success = NSKeyedArchiver.archiveRootObject(alarmItems, toFile: path)

    if success {
        print("Saved Alarms")
    } else {
        print("Didn't Save Alarms")
    }

}
```

I reference a path variable this is set in my ViewDidLoad() Function

```
path = fileInDocumentsDirectory("alarms.plist")
```

Now when I run the app and add an alarm and click the save button it crashes with the following error

> *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[SavingAlarmsApp.Alarm encodeWithCoder:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fbe3ac789a0'

what am I doing wrong here? I have been able to save an array of strings just fine with this code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You just forgot about Alarm class. It should implement NSCoding protocol too.